# JS, React, fetch запрос вне componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

Научился пользоваться **fetch** в рамках события **componentDidMount**, все работает.

```js
componentDidMount() {
  this.updateWindowDimensions();
  window.addEventListener('resize', this.updateWindowDimensions);
  
  fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({
    center: [data.latitude, data.longitude]
  }));
};
```

Но реакт не разрешает такое в других ивентах, например:

```js
 updateCenter(e, country) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const link = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + country + '?fullText=true';
    fetch(link)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({
      center: [data.latitude, data.longitude]
    }));
  };
```

Получаю ошибку:

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component. More info: https://fb.me/react-controlled-components

Хотелось бы как-нибудь воспользоваться данными из запроса в рамках event'а. Знает кто-нибудь как это сделать?

**Render()**

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <NavBar onSubmit={this.updateCenter} />
        </div>
        <div>
          <Map 
            center={this.state.center}
            zoom={this.state.zoom} 
            height={this.state.height - 70} 
            width={this.state.width} 
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: а покажите как выглядет `render()`?

Comment: ошибка не про фетч, а про то что у вас инпут, который ни как не контролируется ( нет обработчика, но при этом туда записывается какое-то значение )

Comment: нужен код `render`

Comment: Ошибка про фетч, мой инпут контролируется в дочернем компоненте.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не рассчитывал, что ответы будут так скоро. Поэтому закрыл все и пошел заниматься сторонними вещами.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Input** в дочернем компоненте был контролируемым. Когда ссылка обработчика события **onSubmit** родительского компонента передавалась в дочерний, React принимал это как изменение состояния.

В родительском компоненте код не менял.

Код дочернего компонента, корректный:

```js
export default function NavBar(props) {
    const classes = useStyle();
    let _searchInput = React.createRef();

    return(
        <div className={classes.root}>
            <AppBar position="static" className={classes.appbar}>
                <Toolbar>
                    <form onSubmit={(e) => props.onSubmit(e, _searchInput.ownerDocument.activeElement.value)}>
                        <div className={classes.search}>
                            <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                                <SearchIcon />
                            </div>
                            <InputBase
                                placeholder="search"
                                inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search'}}
                                classes={{
                                    root: classes.inputRoot,
                                    input: classes.inputInput,
                                }}
                                name='search'
                                ref={ input => _searchInput = input } 
                            />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </Toolbar>
            </AppBar>
        </div>
    );
};
```

Полезные ссылки:

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

https://scotch.io/tutorials/5-most-common-dropdown-use-cases-solved-with-react-downshift

Answer (score 1):

Запроcы должны делаться перед render. Так как нужно время для его получения и затем обработки.
в componentDidMount(). Вызывайте в нем метод, либо смотрите ЖЦ React

Comment: Да, но можно же добавить задержку, пока данные запрашиваются.

Данные запрашиваются, зависимо от названия страны введенной в input. Это убийство времени, прописывать характеристики о каждой стране. Можно написать, конечно скрипт, который соберет их на стороне сервера, но хотелось бы как-то лениво получать это, чтобы их не хранить.

Comment: Все верно. Я так понимаю вы принимаете массив данных. Скорее всего у вас проблемы с определением массива. Нужен ввесь код, а не отрывки. Вот это вам поможет
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37427508/react-changing-an-uncontrolled-input

Comment: С массивом я еще ничего не делал. Такие проблемы решаются, на самом деле, просто через console.log() 
C:

Я уверен, что проблема в fetch,  в том что, запросы делаются после render. Уверен также, что должен быть обходной путь, чтобы не запрашивать тучу данных в самом начале, а делать это уже после componentDidMount, например: на onSubmit.

Comment: Без fetch в событии updateCenter могу собрать, все что мне нужно.

Comment: Решение будет таким. Создайте костомный компонент с помощью props input.js  со своим componentDidMount. В главном файле будут подаваться данные для поиска в костомный компонент, а в input.js будет искать. 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/5-most-common-dropdown-use-cases-solved-with-react-downshift

Comment: Не совсем подходило для меня, но благодаря вам вышел на ответ! Спасибо!

Comment: Это хорошая практика. Которая позволяет гибко работать с проектами.Всегда стремитесь  ее использовать. Так как она уменьшает код и позволяет использовать компонент в нескольких местах.

Answer (score 0):

В componentWillMont создай переменую например this.unmont = false;

```
componentWillMont(){
    this.unmount = false;
}
 componentWillUnmont(){
    this.unmont = true;
}
```

И когда хочешь сделать setstate после запроса проверь this.unmont чтобы было ровно false
Пример

```
updateCenter(e, country) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const link = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/' + country + '?fullText=true';
    fetch(link)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => 
      if(!this.unmont){
         this.setState({
         center: [data.latitude]             
    })
}
);
  };
```